# Webparts in zones or page content

Tags: 2010, web-part, web-part-zone

I did not realise it was so easy just to add webparts to page content and that they did not have to go into web part zones. Is there any reason to continue using zones for general web parts on a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you want your users to do.

If primarily you want them to merge text/content and web parts in an area then use Page Content for that.

If primarily you just want them to add web parts and no text/content then use a web part zone.

Depending on the available web parts they can still do what they want, but you may want to guide them.